# Why are class instance variables persisting across specs?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm using *class instance variables* to keep track of @instances. When I run each spec individually, they pass. But when I run all of the together, there is unexpected behavior.

```
it "returns 1" do
  mock = Mock.new
  expect(Mock.count).to eq(1)
end

it "returns 2" do
  mock = Mock.new
  mock = Mock.new
  expect(Mock.count).to eq(2)
end
```

When I run either individually, all specs are green. But when I run both, the second spec returns a count of 3. So I see that Mock is somehow persisting across specs. I'm using plain ruby, no DB or rails or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

```
before do
  @Mock = Class.new.include(IDable)
end
```

Then each time @Mock is used, it will have fresh class instance variables!

Comment: It's a solution, alright. But is it a good one? This is debatable. If it works for you, I'm all for it. But I'd hesitate to use this in my code. Looks like sweeping the problem under the rug. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: So what would you consider a better solution? I would love to hear it!

Comment: Without knowing anything about the problem you're trying to solve, I'd go with clearing/resetting state in a before block (as mentioned in the other comment)

Answer (score 4):

That's what class instance variables **do**. They are state of the class itself, which normally persists through the lifetime of the app (or test suite run, in your case).

Comment: Is there any way to get around this? I understand that's what class instance variables do, but I want each spec to run in isolation, as if no other code was ran before.

Comment: @thesimpledev Well, no isolation for you, but you can reset that class-level cache in a `before :each` block

Comment: How exactly do you do that?